# NGINX: remove part of url permanantly

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-location

I have redesigned a website and changed the url formats too.
Now i need to change the old url to new one.

Here is my old url:

```
http://www.example.com/forum/showPost/2556/Urgent-Respose
```

The new url will be:

```
http://www.example.com/2556/Urgent-Respose
```

How to redirect to new url using nginx by removing `/forum/showPost` from url?

Edited:
Also this url:

```
http://www.tikshare.com/business/showDetails/1/Pulkit-Sharma-and-Associates,-Chartered-Accountants-in-Bangalore
```

New url:

```
http://www.tikshare.com/classifieds/1/Pulkit-Sharma-and-Associates,-Chartered-Accountants-in-Bangalore
```

Above link is complete removing whereas this link is to replace `business/showDetails` with `classifieds`

Comment: Please refer following url, uses same kind of solution :
http://serverfault.com/questions/302509/how-to-quick-and-easy-remove-part-of-an-url-in-nginx-with-httprewritemodule

Comment: @Opv please explain in comment where to put it and only one line will work. New to servers tech.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
server 
{
    listen 80; ## Listen on port 80 ##
    server_name example.com;  ## Domain Name ##
    index index.html index.php;  ## Set the index for site to use ##
    charset utf-8; ## Set the charset ##
    location ^~ /forum/showPost {
        rewrite ^/forum/showPost(.*)$ $1 permanent;
    }
    location ^~ /business/showDetails {     
        rewrite ^(.*)business/showDetails(.*)$ classifieds$1 permanent;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited the question. Please please solve second also. It will help many users like me.

Comment: why $2 instead of $1. Richards answer also working with $1.

Comment: rewrite ^(.*)business/showDetails(.*)$  classifieds$1 permanent; This will also work.

Comment: @Opv your `$1` will only capture the leading `/`. `rewrite` operates on a *normalised* URI which does not include the scheme, server name or query string.

Answer (score 10):

There are a number of options. You could protect the rewrite within a location block which would be quite efficient as the regular expression is only tested if the URI prefix matches:

```
location ^~ /forum/showPost {
    rewrite ^/forum/showPost(.*)$ $1 permanent;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.

You used *permanent* in your question - which generates a 301 response.

If you use `redirect` instead of `permanent` - a 302 response will be generated.

If you use `last` instead of `permanent` - an internal redirect will occur and the browser address bar will continue to show the old URL.

In response to your comment:

```
rewrite ^/forum/showPost(.*)$ /post$1 permanent;
```

Comment: Thank you. It works but is it 301 redirect. Also suppose if my new url contains new word like say http://www.example.com/post/2556/Urgent-Respose.
What should be changed?

Comment: firefox gives 414 error. URI too large. Worked well on safari.

Comment: Look at your `nginx` access log and Firefox's `Live HTTP Headers` to try to diagnose the problem, The `rewrite` itself is fine - there must be some other interaction going on. Also, clear the Firefox cache, as it can be difficult to diagnose problems in the presence of stale cache data.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Made my day.